# org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, classcastexception, spring-boot-actuator

```
@RestController
public class ChangePasswordController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @PostMapping("/change-password")
    public Response processChangePassword(@RequestParam String newPassword, @RequestParam String oldPass,
            @RequestParam long tenantId) throws ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        CustomUserDetails details = (CustomUserDetails) authentication
                .getPrincipal();
        User user = details.getUser();

        if (oldPass.equals(newPassword)) {
            return new Response("Your new password must be different than the old one.", null, new Date(),
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
        }
        if (!passwordEncoder.matches(oldPass, user.getPassword())) {
            return new Response("Your old password is incorrect.", null, new Date(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value()); 

        } else {
            userService.changePassword(user, newPassword, tenantId);
            return new Response("password change sucessfully !", null, new Date(), HttpStatus.OK.value());
        }

    }
}
```

Above is my code and when I Call the API `/change password`. It give me an  error `java.lang.ClassCastException:`

the error details is bellow

**ERROR**

```
2023-01-09 16:43:13 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api/tenant-service] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to class com.shopwaala.tenant.master.service.CustomUserDetails (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User and com.shopwaala.tenant.master.service.CustomUserDetails are in unnamed module of loader 'app')] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to class com.ABC.tenant.master.service.CustomUserDetails (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User and com.shopwaala.tenant.master.service.CustomUserDetails are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.shopwaala.auth.controller.ChangePasswordController.processChangePassword(ChangePasswordController.java:32)
```